# limit characters when posting from form

Tags: forms, limit, characters

I have a form were users can post question on my page and I would like to limit the characters in the description part of the form. It would also be a plus if I could get a word counter to work.

The form:

```
            <p><label for="title">Titel</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title2" />
            </p>

            <p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Kategorier&tab_index=4&taxonomy=register_vote_category&hide_empty=0' ); ?></p>

            <p><label for="description">Beskrivning</label><br />
            <textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description2" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Skicka" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit2" /></p>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
        </form>
```

The php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])) {

            $title = $_POST['title2'];
            $description = $_POST['description2'];

            if(strlen($title) <= 0 || strlen($description) <= 0){


                echo wpautop( 'Du måste skriva i både titel och beskrivning' );

            }
            else if (strlen($title) >= 1 && strlen($description) >= 1) {

            $new_post = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $description,
                'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
                'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
                'post_type' => 'category-vote'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
            );
            //save the new post
            $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
            //insert taxonomies
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

To limit characters add this to your textarea: `maxlength="200"` changing "200" to whatever you want the character limit to be.

```
<textarea id="description" maxlength="200" tabindex="3" name="description2" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
```

For a character counter you will need some basic Javascript, something like this:

```
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#description').val();

    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#totalChars').html(0);
        return;
    }

    var totalChars = value.length;

    $('#totalChars').html(totalChars); //change the selector to whatever the ID of your counter area is
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').change(counter);
    $('#description').keydown(counter);
    $('#description').keypress(counter);
    $('#description').keyup(counter);
    $('#description').blur(counter);
    $('#description').focus(counter);
});
```